# how to bullet or number text of richtextbox silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am using Silverlight RichTextEditor ( [reference](https://richtexteditor.codeplex.com/) ) that does not have bulleting or numbering of text. Is there any way to do so in a simpler manner.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to apply bullets/numbering/indent to selected-text in a RichTextBox, then you have to programmatically find Paragraph elements inside selected-text and insert the corresponding character (bullet or number of tab) at the start of each Paragraph element.

Check out [here](http://www.codeding.com/?article=22) for detailed explanation.

Or,

Check out the ordered/unordered list controls explained in [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26788/Numbered-And-Bulleted-Lists-for-Silverlight) link. You can extend its functionality to acheive what you intend to do. I have used it to show hierarchical data using nested lists and found it fairly easy to modify it to my needs.

Comment: Thanks, i got the Bullets for richtextbox.